# understanding __FILE__

Tags: ruby

I know that in Ruby `__FILE__` refers to the current file, but what does it refer to when creating a path such as this and why is it needed as a second argument to expand_path?

```
set :views, File.expand_path('../../views', __FILE__)
```

For example, if `__FILE__` refers to the current file, but there happens to be more than one file in the views folder, what exactly does `__FILE__` refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a relative path in `'../../views'`, you need a reference point to expand the path. The second argument, which happens to be `__FILE__` in this case, overrides the default reference point, which is the current working directory.

[Ruby Doc File.expand_path](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path)